# js strange return statement

Tags: javascript

I am doing an angular tutorial, but regardless, I do not understand the following return statement:

```
return selectedCategory == null || product.category == selectedCategory;
```

I tried rewriting it like so but it does not work:

```
if (selectedCategory == null) {
                return selectedCategory;
            } else {
                return product.category;
            }
```

How could the one liner code be rewritten so as to be more easily understood?

Answer (score 2):

Yours returns null, theirs returns true. Yours would need to be

```
if (selectedCategory == null) {
    return true;
} else {
    return product.category == selectedCategory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How could the one liner code be rewritten so as to be more easily understood?

By putting some parenthesis around the returned expression:

```
return ((selectedCategory == null) || (product.category == selectedCategory));
```

It simply returns a boolean value. This should not be split up, using an `if`-statement makes it harder to read in fact. If at all, you could introduce some extra variables to give descriptive names to the single values:

```
// some guesses about their meaning
var noSelection   = selectedCategory == null;
var alreadyActive = product.category == selectedCategory;
var nothingTodo   = noSelection || alreadyActive;
return nothingTodo;
```

Comment: @naortor You're probably right, but I wanted to keep the code as close as possible to the original